# How do I remove a spurious tag in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm pulling text from the Presidential debates.  I got to [one](http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=111395) that has an issue: it errantly turns every mention of the word "debate" into a tag`<debate>`.  Go ahead, search for "Welcome back to the Republican presidential"; notice an obvious word missing?

Cool, so BeautifulSoup does a superb job of cleaning up messy HTML and adding closing tags were they *should* have been.  But in this case, that mucks me up, because `<debate>` is now a child of a `<p>` and the closing `</debate>` is added allllll the way at the end; thus nesting the remaining debate inside that tag.

How do I tell BeautifulSoup to either ignore or remove `<debate>`?  Or alternatively, how do I add a closing tag immediately after?  I've tried unwrap, but by the time I can call it, BS has already set up the closing tag at the end, and thus made following paragraphs children rather than siblings.

Here's how I'm set up:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

bad_debate = 'http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=111395'
file = urllib.urlopen(bad_debate)
soup = BeautifulSoup(file)
```

My hunch is I need to insert something between the url call and BeautifulSoup, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to modify the file contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`html5lib` parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) does a better job (than `lxml` or `html.parser`) handling the `debate` element in this case:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(file, "html5lib")
```

Here is how it handles the mentioned part of the debate:

```
<p>
    <b>
     BARTIROMO:
    </b>
    Welcome back to the Republican presidential
    <debate>
     here in North Charleston. Right back to the questions. [
     <i>
      applause
     </i>
     ]
    </debate>
</p>
```

Comment: It doesn't error out, but now it won't use lines that worked on other transcripts fine.  eg transcript = soup.find_all("span", class_="displaytext")[0]   (out of bounds), when I run print soup.prettify() I can see the span I'm trying to call, but find_all won't grab it.

Comment: @ScottieB could you please create a separate question providing the code you have so far and describing the symptoms? Throw me a link here. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe for the suggestion, posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052097/html5lib-makes-beautifulsoup-miss-an-element